# exception Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 0

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` here. What am I missing ?

My code is below:

```
public class Exercise {

    public static double[] strfloat(String str){
        double[] f = new double[] {};
        String[] st = new String[] {};
        st= str.split(" "); 
        for(int i = 0; i < st.length; i++){ 
            System.out.println(st[i]); 
            f[i] = Double.parseDouble(st[i]);
            System.out.println(f[i]);
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "1.99999996e-002 7.49999983e-003 0. 1.75000001e-002 9.99999978e-003";
        double[] retstr = strfloat(str);

        for(int i = 0; i < retstr.length; i++){
            System.out.println(retstr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: double[] f = new double[st.length] -- Use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
String[] st = str.split(" ");
double[] f = new double[st.length];
```

In that way, you initialize the array `f` to the size of the string chunks.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
double[] f = new double[] {};
```

is empty and you're referencing it's (non-existing) elements.

```
System.out.println(f[i]);
```

Before you print `f[i]`, make sure it even exists.

You can fix it like that:

```
String[] st = str.split(" ");
double[] f = new double[st.length];
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
String[] st = new String[]{};

st= str.split(" ");

double[] f = new double[st.length()];
```

**Reason Behind this**

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed
>   with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or
>   equal to the size of the array

Here you have initialized the double array f with empty constant initializer. so the length of f is 0. But you are trying to acess f[i]. That's why the problem occured

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `f` array:

```
    double[] f = new double[st.length];
```

Now you may wonder why you don't have to do this to `st` if you declared it in a similar way?
In fact, it's not necessary to instantiate `st` as you did, because `str.split()` returns a different array instance anyway!

```
    String[] st = str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty array here:

```
double[] f = new double[] {};
```

Create your array using st.length, after the split. That way you'll have the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

> arrayoutofboundexception here. What i am missing ?

You miss the end of `f`...

```
double[] f = new double[] {};

[...]
for(int i=0; i<st.length; i++){
    [...]
    f[i] = Double.parseDouble(st[i]);
```

f has a length of 0 so you exceed its length when you try to access f[0]

rearrange your code a bit:

```
String[] st = st= str.split(" ");
double[] f = new double[st.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize double array `f`. Try this.

`double[] f = new double[st.length]`.

In your code:

```
public static double[] strfloat(String str) {
        String[] st = new String[]{};
        st = str.split(" ");
        double[] f = new double[st.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(st[i]);
            f[i] = Double.parseDouble(st[i]);
            System.out.println(f[i]);
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "1.99999996e-002 7.49999983e-003 0. 1.75000001e-002 9.99999978e-003";
        double[] retstr = strfloat(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < retstr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(retstr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if my string contains "[" how can i ignore this. eg. str = "[ 1.99999996e-002 ... ]". I tried it with this code but getting some errors. Code: for(int i=0; i<st.length; i++){ if!(st[i].equals("[") ||(st[i].equals("]"))){f[i]=Double.parseDouble(st[i]); } }